# Renaming the target variable's class names of trained Sklearn classifier mode

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, pickle

I have created a model that predicts the name of a flower based on its features using `LinearSVC` in `sklearn` and saved the model using `pickle`.

for example my target variables are `lily` and `rose` - so given the features the model has the capability to return either `lily` or `rose` as the flower name.

At a later stage i want to rename `lily` to `lilly` as i felt that is a better name.

I know of two methods to achieve this.

One is to retrain the model by renaming the target variables of `lily` to `lilly` in my traning data, which means my model in future will return `lilly` and `rose

The other is to keep the model as it is and then after prediction use a mapping dictionary `{'lily' : 'lilly','rose': 'rose'}` to get the renamed value.

Is there any other way to tweek the existing model which is saved after pickling so that the model returns `lily` as `lilly` from now on?

thanks for helping

Answer (score 2):

You just have to update the `classes` variable of the classifier after you load your pickle file.
Quick example with LinearSVC. This can work for any Sklearn compatible classifier.

```py
>>> from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
>>> svc = LinearSVC(random_state=42).fit(df.data, df.target)
>>> svc.predict(df.data.iloc[0:2, :])
array(['setosa', 'setosa'], dtype=object)
>>> svc.classes_ = np.array(['class1', 'class2', 'class3'])
>>> svc.predict(df.data.iloc[0:2, :])
array(['class1', 'class1'], dtype='<U6')
```